# How To Prevent Over Scrolling in Scroll Viewer Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1, scrollviewer, stackpanel

I am developing wp 8.1 app. I have a stack panel whose contents have to be added dynamically and scrolled vertically. For this, I am using Scroll Viewer outside the stack panel. Contents are scrolling fine. But, My problem is that after the last content, When I scroll, the stack panel itself get scrolled. How to prevent the stack panel to get scrolled.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any other controls other than stackpanel inside the Listview?

Comment: I don't have list view. I have a stack panel in which the contents will be added dynamically(initially zero). I have enclosed stack panel with scroll viewer.

Comment: I  have  similar  problem.

Answer (score 1):

Set the StackPanel.VerticalAlignment to Stretch and set fixed size to the parent ScrollViewer. This is necessary - the ScrollViewer must know its size, to show the scrollbars for the inner content when the inner content is too long. Otherwise It will scroll end of the control and as well as control.

Comment: I have set the height of scrollviewer and changed vertical alignment too to stretch. Still, the stack panel is scrolling up. :(

Comment: The height should be lesser than stack panel"s content height

Comment: Stackpanel's height is not known because, I don't know the number of contents it will fit at run time. But, I have specified a Margin to it. so that if exceeds it, the contents of stackpanel has to be scrolled. That's it. This is my problem.. but, if I remove margin. the stack panel fills the screen and the scrolling works fine. But, this is my condition. My stack panel should be a single row at beginning. On adding children, the height should be increases upto threshold(say 5rows). After that, the size should be fixed and  it should become scrollable on adding child.  Thank you

Comment: I solved it. Just removed the margin and changed vertical alignment= top. :) Thanks for ur help though.